# How to expand selection to include enclosing element in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: code, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

In some IDEs there is a nice feature (named "Expand selection to include enclosing element" in Eclipse). It expands current text selection to 1 level up syntax element. For example, Eclipse does this with `Alt+Shift+UpArrow` hotkey combo, and so do some other IDEs, and IntelliJ IDEA does this with `Alt+UpArrow` hotkey combo. I'm wondering if Sublime Text 3 can do this too. (out of the box or with a plugin - doesn't matter)
I guess, it has enough information to do it if it already does syntax highlighting.

Comment: I recently found [Expand Selection to Quotes](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Expand%20Selection%20to%20Quotes), which works specifically with strings. `Expand Selection to Scope` will select the contents of a string, but not the quotes themselves. With your cursor in a string, hit `Ctrl-'` once to select the string, and hit it again to select the quotes themselves. I work with strings a lot, and I've found it quite useful. The Package Control link claims it only works with ST2, but I just installed it in ST3 on OSX and it works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your syntax, one of the the *Selection » Expand Selection To …* can do it.

For XML, I've found that *Expand Selection to Tag* (repeatedly) works. In Java source code, *Expand Selection to Scope* works. And for any formatted source code, *Expand Selection to Indentation* should work.

Comment: Thanks. But can I set it up so a single hotkey will do it, regardless of current syntax used?
Expand to scope works, but in XML it "jumps too high" at a step.

Comment: @SargeBorsch For code, *… to Scope* works in my experience (don't have that much other source code around right now). Eclipse cannot even do the equivalent *… to Tag*, so you're not losing anything if you're only learning that one.

Comment: Yes, this is cool, the only downside is that this is 2 different commands

Comment: @SargeBorsch That's what I meant. For the equivalent functionality to Eclipse, it's still only one command.

Comment: Maybe I can merge them in single command that will choose what to use depending on syntax type via some Python kung-fu?

Comment: is there a list anywhere, where I can find all the valid args for the command expand_selection, in sublime text?